# map entity property to column from another table using intermediate table

Tags: hibernate

It is sounds complicated but difficult to express in title.
This is common situation I have and may be some other as well.
Let say we have a Car entity, and CarType entity.
CarType is simple and have id, name, and that is almost all.

```
class CarType{
    private long id;
    private String carName;
    private String description;  //not important  - just to ensure  
    private String costValue;   //not important - that we need separate CarType entity
    .....
}
```

entity Car

```
class Car{
    private long id;
    private String carNumber; 
    @ManyToOne             //ManyToOne using extra table
    private CarType carType;
    .....
}
```

this is common situation. And as well common situation to have on webpage table with cars.
It takes a lot of code to render data from Car entity (using jsp or especially then cars list send via json ajax request). It is not difficult to code but in case of json ajax request, js can be huge.

Problem is that most of time i need to know only cartype.carName. Rest of fields are just helpers and in reality nether get visualized.

How to map field in extra helper entity:

```
 class CarTable{  // entity map to same db table as Car entity
      private long id;
      private String carName;
      **//here mapping which i dont know how to implement**
      private String carType;
 }
```

It is not crucial, but in my case it is often situation, which need routine work to be done either on server side preprocessing, either in jsp processing, either in js postprocessing.

If someone have any ideas to share or know answer

Answer (score 0):

If you need the data for display only, you can define a view in the DB containing only the relevant columns and an entity mapped to the view:

```
@Entity
class CarView{
    private long id;
    private String carNumber; 
    private CarType carName;
    .....
}
```

Do not use the view-backed entity to modify the data.